# exclusive access could not be obtained

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012, database-restore

I was trying to restore my backup database in vb.net but I encounter this problem  what is the problem here?

[This is the image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1ZIO.png)

This is the code that I am using.

```vb
Private Sub btnRestore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRestore.Click
    Try
        Dim con2 As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand
        Dim Filename2 As String
        Dim strQuery2 As String
        Dim database2 As String
        Dim get_servername2 As String
        'get value in selected database name dropdown menu in combo box
        database2 = cmbdatabase.Text
        get_servername2 = cmbservername.Text.Trim 'selecting servername
        Dim opendlg As New OpenFileDialog
        Dim constr2 As String
        constr2 = "Data Source=" & get_servername2 & ";Initial Catalog=master; Integrated Security= True "
        If opendlg.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
            con2 = New SqlConnection(constr2)
            con2.Open()
            Filename2 = opendlg.FileName
            strQuery2 = " Restore database " & database2 & " from disk = '" & Filename2 & "'"

            'exe command
            Try
                cmd2 = New SqlCommand(strQuery2, con2)
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Database " & database2 & " has been restored successfully. ", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                con2.Close()
                Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
            Catch ex As Exception
                Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End Try
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of changing the error message in the (already answered) question, you should accept the answer here and create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Your connectionstring uses the database `Payroll` as `Intial Catalog`.

As stated in the message, it's recommended to use the `master`-database instead, when performing this operation.

Change the `Initial Catalog` to `master` and it should work:

```
constr2 = "Data Source=" & get_servername2 & ";Initial Catalog=master; Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: If you simply omit the `Initial Catalog` attribute altogether then I believe that the master database is assumed. Not that it's wrong to be explicit though.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes and no. Depends on the configuration of the [`DEFAULT_DATABASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)-option of the user. When not explicitly set, then `master` is used by default.